# Create a new Telegram bot

Tags: php, wordpress, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin using a Telegram Bot to send notification to a channel.
I can send a command to my already created BOT in this way:
https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/[command]

Is it possible to create a new BOT by code?
e.g. sending the following command or similar

https://api.telegram.org/bot[@BotFather]/newbot

Thanks
Enzo

Comment: you should probably regenerate that bot token you posted now, because that's supposed to be private and will give anyone who has it control over your bot.

Answer (score 2):

Creating bots using the **Telegram Bot API** is currently not possible.

However, you could use the **Telegram API** which is generally used to make clients, to interact with Botfather. This would be way more complicated than a single HTTP request though.

Comment: Better way is just write small instruction for user about how to create new Bot and on Wordpress's plugin make field for token